# Group table columns by using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, group-by, html-table

Output:

[image: Current Output Image]

Expected:

[image: Expected Output Image]

So what I like to do is create a responsive design, so that when the web-page is viewed in desktop screen, the table is displayed as above.
I like to use CSS, JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY & HTML to achieve the above. I am attaching my code below:

**CODE**:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what you look for is probably rowspan attribute straight into your HTML. example https://jsfiddle.net/prm7toxh/

Comment: I am fetching data from database, so I cannot do rowspan hardcoded